# Does GCM maintains empty groups?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a following use case

A user login from his device and a new group is created if not exists and token_id for this device is added in the newely created group.

Again a same user login with diff device then token_id is added to the existing group.

Now user logout from both device and I remove both token_id from group doing nothing to the group and now the group have no token_ids in it.

Same user login again and I try to add the retrieved token_id to the same group using notification_key_name and notification_key but then gcm response with following error message "notification_key not found".

So does this mean gcm deletes the group in which there are no token_id present??

Comment: Are you referring to Device Group Messaging by GCM?

Comment: There's nothing about it listed on the GCM documentation. So, my take on it would be that GCM doesn't delete the empty groups. However, that doesn't seem to be the case in what you're experiencing. The best I can think of is for you to create another device group when re-logging in.

Comment: Thank You @adjuremods
I'm currently doing the same thing suggested by you. i.e re-creating the group if getting error from gcm server.
But since gcm allows me to create group with the same notification-key-name then shouldn't we conclude that gcm destroys empty device groups??

Comment: Yes, that will be the case for GCM. I think its still best that its indicated in the documentation as well. Hopefully someone from Google can see this!